# How to add a <svg> Element to an existing <svg>Tag via PHP?

Tags: php, html, svg

I have a `<svg>`-Tag and want to add some `<circle>` elements to it dynamically.

This is the `<svg>`-Tag:

```
<svg xmlns="..." version="1.1"
    width="400" height="600" viewBox="0 0 400 600">
      
    <image xlink:href="<?=$map->ImagePath?>" x="0"y="0"height="100%"/>
    
    <?php echo $this->calcCircles(); ?>

</svg>
```

This ist the PHP function in which the circles are generated

```
public function calcCircles(){
  $circles='';
  foreach(...){
          ... 
         $circles.='<circle cx="'.$xValue.'" cy="'.$differenceY.'" r="10" fill="#..." .../>';
  }
  return $circles;
}
```

Are there any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: If `calcCircles` is a function call, then doing `<?php $calcCircles?>` would be wrong. You would instead do `<?php echo self::calcCircles();?>` or `<?php echo $this->calcCircles();?>` depending on the object use. (and add a `return $circles;` inside that function)

Comment: Shouldn't you be `echo`ing somewhere? Apparently calcCircles() isn't echoing or returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

Since `calcCircles` is an object method, then doing `<?php $calcCircles?>` would be wrong.

You would instead do `<?php echo $yourObject->calcCircles();?>` and return the `$circles` inside that method with `return $circles;`:

```
<svg xmlns="..." version="1.1"
    width="400" height="600" viewBox="0 0 400 600">
      
    <image xlink:href="<?=$map->ImagePath?>" x="0"y="0"height="100%"/>
    
    <?php echo $yourObject->calcCircles(); ?>

</svg>
```

```
public function calcCircles(){
    $circles = '';
    foreach(...){
        ... 
        $circles .= '<circle cx="'.$xValue.'" cy="'.$differenceY.'" r="10" fill="#..." .../>';
    }
    return $circles; // return the value
}
```

Note in this example it is unknown the object name because you did not provide that. Use what you have setup. If the svg generation is inside the SAME object as `calcCircles()` then use `$this->calcCircles()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question, but the circles aren't displayed anyway.

Comment: Could it be a problem, that the $circles are saved as strings?

Comment: No. An SVG is a string by nature. All content going back to the browser, is a giant string for the browser to interpret. So if the above is not working, it may be that you are creating invalid svg syntax. You would need to look at your web browsers devtools, and the network tab, look at the raw html coming from your PHP, and then carefully inspect the bit about the svg. If you could, add the "output" to your question as what your PHP is outputting to the browser.